# how to use a variable in RegExp with search method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string:

```
var _codes = "1234,1414,5555,3333,2222,5566,4545";
var regex = new RegExp(/1234/i);
var _found = _codes.search(regex);

//this works sofar.
```

nowi  want to do it with variable:

like this:

```
var id = "1234";
regex = new RegExp("\\"+id+"\\/i");
```

but it doesn't work. any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using the `RegExp` constructor, you don't supply delimiters and the flags go in the second argument.

```
var id = "1234";
regex = new RegExp(id, "i");
```

However, the RegExp just for `1234` with `i` doesn't really make sense. Use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) instead.

However, perhaps you really did mean to match numbers surrounded with a `\`. In that case, leave them in there.

Comment: And the `i` flag (case insensitive) doesn't make much sense when the expression is only digits.

Comment: @RobG Yep, I mentioned that above :)